# How do I check if a field has been set in Chapel?

Tags: chapel

I want to see if an integer field has been set in a class

```
class BounceHouse {
  var age: int;
}

var v = new BounceHouse();
if v.age != nil {
    writeln("not nil");
}

v.age = 17;
```

But I get an error at compile time.  What is the correct method to see if `age` has been set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common answer is to use a sentinel value for age, like `-1`.  Then if you check its value and it is `-1`, you know it hasn't been set (unless someone maliciously set it to `-1`).

You could use a `sync` or `single` variable, which will give you a `empty`/`full` state to check, though that might add a bit of a performance penalty and is probably not the exact functionality you want (since there are ways to reset the value for `sync`s and maybe you don't care about parallel safety for it).

The third option is to add an additional boolean field tracking whether it has been set, and override the setter for the field you are tracking to update when it has been given a value.

```
class BounceHouse {
  var age: int;
  var ageIsSet = false;

  // setter override
  inline proc age ref {
    ageIsSet = true;
    return age;
  }

  // getter override, so we don't accidentally think
  // age was set when someone was just looking at it
  inline proc age const ref {
    return age;
  }
}

var v = new BounceHouse();
writeln(v.age);
if v.ageIsSet {
    writeln("set");
}

v.age = 17;

if v.ageIsSet {
  writeln("set here too");
}
```

Note that the third option can also be tricked if you assign age to a `ref` variable, or send it as an argument to a function with `ref` intent - it will think you're setting age to something but its value will be unchanged.  And of course, since Chapel doesn't support private fields (yet), someone could set `ageIsSet` maliciously.